# Serilog timestamp missmatch?

Tags: c#, sequence, serilog

I have several .NET services that use Serilog to log data to SEQ. Some of the service are located local so they log to SEQ direcly. The other services can´t reach SEQ so the need to send the LogEvent to a LogService in my network first.

The problem is that the timestamp is incorrect so some logs do not show in the proper order in SEQ.

The external service transform LogEvent to JSON like this :

```
 var jsonFormatter = new CompactJsonFormatter();
 var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
 jsonFormatter.Format(logEvent, stringWriter);
 var jsonLogEvent = stringWriter.ToString();
```

LogService transform JSON to LogEvent like this :

```
var stringReader = new StringReader(jsonLogEvent);
var logEventReader = new LogEventReader(stringReader);
logEventReader.TryRead(out LogEvent deserializedLogEvent);
```

I can see that the CompactJsonFormatter.Format will change the time when converting it to UTC and this change presists in the re-created LogEvent so I suspect that this is the problem.

Is there a built-in solution for this? else I will have to build a custom formatter or manipulate time after the re-creation.